# SQL Fuzzy Join - MSSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I have two sets of data. Existing customers and potential customers.

My main objective is to figure out if any of the potential customers are already existing customers. However, the naming conventions of customers across data sets are inconsistent.

**EXISTING CUSTOMERS**

```
Customer /  ID
Ed's Barbershop /   1002
GroceryTown /   1003
Candy Place /   1004
Handy Man / 1005
```

**POTENTIAL CUSTOMERS**

```
Customer
Eds Barbershop
Grocery Town
Candy Place
Handee Man
Beauty Salon
The Apple Farm
Igloo Ice Cream
Ride-a-Long Bikes
```

I would like to write some type of select statement like below to reach my objective:

```
SELECT a.Customer, b.ID
FROM PotentialCustomers a LEFT JOIN
     ExistingCustomers B
     ON a.Customer = b.Customer
```

The results would look something like:

```
Customer /  ID
Eds Barbershop  / 1002
Grocery Town    / 1003
Candy Place / 1004
Handee Man  / 1005
Beauty Salon /  NULL
The Apple Farm /    NULL
Igloo Ice Cream / NULL
Ride-a-Long Bikes / NULL
```

I am vaguely familiar with the concepts of Levenshtein Distance and Double Metaphone but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Ideally I would want the JOIN portion of the SELECT statement to read something like: `LEFT JOIN ExistingCustomers as B WHERE a.Customer LIKE b.Customer` but I know that syntax is incorrect.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how this could be done using Levenshtein Distance:

Create this function:(Execute this first)

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_levenshtein(@s1 nvarchar(3999), @s2 nvarchar(3999))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @s1_len int, @s2_len int
 DECLARE @i int, @j int, @s1_char nchar, @c int, @c_temp int
 DECLARE @cv0 varbinary(8000), @cv1 varbinary(8000)

 SELECT
  @s1_len = LEN(@s1),
  @s2_len = LEN(@s2),
  @cv1 = 0x0000,
  @j = 1, @i = 1, @c = 0

 WHILE @j <= @s2_len
  SELECT @cv1 = @cv1 + CAST(@j AS binary(2)), @j = @j + 1

 WHILE @i <= @s1_len
 BEGIN
  SELECT
   @s1_char = SUBSTRING(@s1, @i, 1),
   @c = @i,
   @cv0 = CAST(@i AS binary(2)),
   @j = 1

  WHILE @j <= @s2_len
  BEGIN
   SET @c = @c + 1
   SET @c_temp = CAST(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j+@j-1, 2) AS int) +
    CASE WHEN @s1_char = SUBSTRING(@s2, @j, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   IF @c > @c_temp SET @c = @c_temp
   SET @c_temp = CAST(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j+@j+1, 2) AS int)+1
   IF @c > @c_temp SET @c = @c_temp
   SELECT @cv0 = @cv0 + CAST(@c AS binary(2)), @j = @j + 1
 END

 SELECT @cv1 = @cv0, @i = @i + 1
 END

 RETURN @c
END
```

(Function developped by Joseph Gama)

And then simply use this query to get matches

```
SELECT A.Customer,
       b.ID,
       b.Customer
FROM #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS a
     LEFT JOIN #ExistingCustomers b ON dbo.ufn_levenshtein(REPLACE(A.Customer, ' ', ''), REPLACE(B.Customer, ' ', '')) < 5;
```

Complete Script after you create that function:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExistingCustomers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ExistingCustomers;

CREATE TABLE #ExistingCustomers
(Customer VARCHAR(255),
 ID       INT
);

INSERT INTO #ExistingCustomers
VALUES
('Ed''s Barbershop',
 1002
);

INSERT INTO #ExistingCustomers
VALUES
('GroceryTown',
 1003
);

INSERT INTO #ExistingCustomers
VALUES
('Candy Place',
 1004
);

INSERT INTO #ExistingCustomers
VALUES
('Handy Man',
 1005
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#POTENTIALCUSTOMERS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS;

CREATE TABLE #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS(Customer VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Eds Barbershop');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Grocery Town');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Candy Place');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Handee Man');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Beauty Salon');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('The Apple Farm');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Igloo Ice Cream');

INSERT INTO #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS
VALUES('Ride-a-Long Bikes');

SELECT A.Customer,
       b.ID,
       b.Customer
FROM #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS a
     LEFT JOIN #ExistingCustomers b ON dbo.ufn_levenshtein(REPLACE(A.Customer, ' ', ''), REPLACE(B.Customer, ' ', '')) < 5;
```

Here you can find a T-SQL example at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/fuzzy-string-matching-using-levenshtein-distance-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Closest I've gotten so far, but still some issues. First, it is taking a very long time to run the query. Secondly, I am getting a large amount of false positive matches. For example, one of my potential customers is matching 700 existing customers ...

Is there a way just to get the levenshtein  distance as a column in the select statement?

Comment: use this:  SELECT A.Customer,
       b.ID,
       b.Customer,
    dbo.ufn_levenshtein(REPLACE(A.Customer, ' ', ''), REPLACE(B.Customer, ' ', '')) 
FROM #POTENTIALCUSTOMERS a
     LEFT JOIN #ExistingCustomers b ON dbo.ufn_levenshtein(REPLACE(A.Customer, ' ', ''), REPLACE(B.Customer, ' ', '')) < 5;

Comment: you have to play with distance and see what suites you best..right now its matching "<5". Like iamdave suggested, Performance will always be problem with these kind of matches

Comment: understood. thanks very much for the hand holding. i learned a lot and i appreciate it.

Comment: @KashifQureshi is there a way to match to the lowest Levenshtein score possible? Instead of `<5` and it happening to get 1-1 result. Somehow return the match with the lowest score by default?

Comment: My question in it's own thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393049/sql-function-fuzzy-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-algorithm-return-lowes

Answer (score 5):

Trying to do this within SQL is going to be a continual challenge and one that you are not likely to win.  You can go quite far by stripping out non a-z or 0-9 characters or trying something like [Soundex](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2159/using-soundex-and-difference-to-standardize-data-in-sql-server/) or [Metaphone](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13574) matching or [Levenshtein Distance](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2010/12/sql_server-fuzzy-strings-matching-using-levenshtein-algorithm-t-sql-vs-clr/) but there will always be *another* edge case that you didn't pick up in all your replacing, wild carding, phoneticising or plain fudging.

If you do manage to find something that works with enough accuracy for you, you will then hit performance problems.

In short, your best hope is going way down the SQLCLR route and learning a lot of C# on the way or not really bothering at all and simply cleaning your data at source or creating a lookup table of 'clean' names that will require constant maintenance as new variants come in.

Comment: pretty sure i want to use the Leveshtein Distance example you laid out. I understand it's limitations, but I am just doing exploratory tasks, not looking to automate just yet.

With that said, I have an elementary question. It's easy enough for me to script kitty the Levenshtein function, but would you be able to help me understand how I can pass the two values, PRE EXISTING customer and POTENTIAL customers, into the function?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the help of REPLACE function in both side of the comparing columns.

```
SELECT a.Customer, b.ID
FROM PotentialCustomers a 
  LEFT JOIN ExistingCustomers B
     ON (LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.Customer,' ',''),'-',''),'''',''))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.Customer,' ',''),'-',''),'''','')))) 
        OR (a.Customer LIKE '%'+b.Customer+'%') 
        OR (b.Customer LIKE '%'+a.Customer+'%')
```

Comment: good suggestion but what happens if the company name in one set is **Oracle Inc.** and **Oracle** in another?

Comment: the you need to expand your ON condition.. just see the updated code.

Comment: This is so incredibly short sighted, it doesn't even work on all the examples given in the question.

Comment: i appreciate the suggestion here @UnnikrishnanR but I got too many false positive matches using this specific approach. However, I can use this template as a starting point and tweak it for my data. As iamdave explained, its short sighted and requires a bevy of manual intervention, but I think I can get by with this for the moment. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need more than 1 field to accomplish this with any effectiveness. Do you have things like city, state, zip, address, etc? You can then create a multipart key with those fields concatenated. You may want to truncate some to the first 5 characters or something but the more you vary the more false positives you get.

I’ve done this and created a couple keys being less restrictive with each key. Then match trying each key and assigning a match grade when you find matches.

Comment: Perhaps provide an example of your answer in action in order to facilitate a better discussion for the OP's understanding